# simulate keyup() on a textarea on keyup() of another contenteditable div

Tags: jquery

Here is the scenerio:

1. I have a content editable div. I also have a textarea, on which there are some stuffs happening on .keyup().
2. I need such that, on keyup() of the content editable div, copy the text entered in contenteditable div to the textarea and then trigger the keyup event of the textarea through jquery.

What I have achieved so far:

I found that, keyup() is not triggered until there is a physical click on the textarea. Initially if i do a .trigger('keyup') on textarea nothing happens. but if i click on the textarea, then type anything in the contenteditable div, and do a .trigger('keyup') on textarea, the keyup event of textarea gets fired and everything works like a charm.

Any directions will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What browser are you testing on? This works fine in Chrome 31 and Firefox 24 http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/MGWZY/

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what your problem is. This works fine:

```
var textarea=$('#editable_textarea');
var div=$('#editable_div');

div.on('keyup',function()
{
    textarea.text($(this).text()).trigger('keyup');
});

textarea.on('keyup',function()
{
    console.log('keyup!');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W2P9t/

Comment: One thing to note with this is that if you enter anything into the `textarea` then editing `#editable_div` will no longer affect the value of the `textarea`. You want to use `.val()` on `textarea` instead of `.text()`: http://jsfiddle.net/W2P9t/3/

Answer (score 1):

I did not fully understand your problem, since you unfortunately didn't append any code, but I hope something liek this works for you:

```
// listening for keyup-event in your content div
$(document).on("#mycontentdiv", "keyup", function() {
    // copy text from div to textarea
    $("#mytextarea").text($("#mycontentdiv").text());

    // trigger keyup-event on textarea
    $("#mytextarea").keyup();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

did you try

```
$('#yourinput').keyup();
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you wish to have the exact event in both content editable and textarea, you can achieve it like this:

```
$('#contentEditable').on('keyup', function(e) {
  $('textarea').text($(this).text());
  $('textarea').trigger(e);
});

$('textarea').on('keyup', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

Where HTML part would be like this.

```
<div id="contentEditable" contenteditable>Lorem ipsum</div>
<textarea></textarea>
```